# Change "dude.fbx" model in Skinned Model Sample

Tags: model, xna, rotation

Sorry for beginner question :( I'm new to XNA

I was looking for an sample that describes how to rotate bones in a Model
And i found that http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

there is model named "dude.fbx" in its content
i tried to change the model but it always gives errors like: "No Animation" or "No Skinning Data"

is there any free models like "dude.fbx" that work fine in Skinned Model Sample?
or how can i build models like that?

thanks

(Sorry for bad english ^_^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your model with animations included (I've found that the `.x` file format works better than `.fbx` for this), if you're using 3ds max, I'd suggest using [kW-Xport](http://www.kwxport.org/), which is what I use. If you're using blender, [this](http://directpython.sourceforge.net/exportx.html) seems promising, although I don't have blender to make sure.

Be sure to check any boxes pertaining to animation, so that you export it with the model, and list the animations. In 3ds Max using the exporter I mentioned, you can name multiple animations in a box on the right.

After you bring the model into XNA, make sure that the `Content Processor` is set to the correct item, I believe it's `SkinnedModelProcessor`, or something similar.

Finally, there are some free models on [TurboSquid](http://www.turbosquid.com/XNA)'s XNA page.